# How to display name of current category being searched in osclass

Tags: php, osclass

I want to show name of current category being searched in category field in the header.

I tried this code but it shows "Array".

```
<?php echo osc_search_category(); ?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: TRy ,  $p=array(); $p=osc_search_category(); print_r($p);

Comment: It do not display what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following code working for me

```
$cName = Category::newInstance()->findNameByPrimaryKey(osc_search_category_id());
```